# QDesktopWidget signals not firing in Qt 5.1.1 (they do in Qt 4.8.4)

Tags: qt

I want to resize my window whenever the number of screens or their resolution changes. I have created a minimal C++ application with the QtCreator. I then added these lines into the MainWindow constructor

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    QDesktopWidget* desktop = QApplication::desktop();
    QObject::connect(desktop, SIGNAL(screenCountChanged(int)), this, SLOT(updateScreens()));
    QObject::connect(desktop, SIGNAL(resized(int)), this, SLOT(updateScreens()));
}
```

And here's the function:

```
void MainWindow::updateScreens() {
    qDebug() << "Here";
}
```

I've defined it as a slot in the .h file:

```
class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    .......
public slots:
    void updateScreens();
}
```

If I compile the project with Qt 4.8.4 (Mingw) and run it, then change resolution, I get a `Here` output. If I recompile it with Qt 5.1.1 (Mingw) and run it, then change resolution in exactly the same way, nothing happens.

Is this a bug in the new release? Do I need to do something differently now?
System : Qt 5.1.1 on Windows7 x64 mingw.

Comment: Why is the `updateScreens()` slot in your `MainWindow` class when you are establishing the connection, but then in the code snippet of that slot it belongs to `cOverlayWindowsManager` class? Should it not be `void MainWindow::updateScreens() {`?

Comment: @thuga:
Sorry, a copy-paste artifact (I tried it in my original project before I created this test minimal project). Corrected.

Comment: When I change the resolution and then check the geometry of the desktop widget, I see that its geometry remains the same. So it seems that the desktop widget is not being updated at all, and therefore does not generate the changed signals.

Comment: It seems that I can achieve everything I need with the QScreen new class. The signals work there as expected, it just means I have to rewrite everything in a new way, if there's no solution to this problem.

Comment: This might be related to [this bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-32567). Should be fixed in `5.1.2`.